# Close method not working in Office

Tags: winforms, office-interop

Im trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.Close() in a .net 3.5 windows form app.

No matter how much I search here and on Google I cannot find the correct parameters to put in the Close method.

I am using version 14.0.0.0 of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and I would like to close the document without saving and ideally ensure that the application can isolate the document thread so that users can still open word documents outside the running application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
object doNotSaveChanges = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
object missing =  System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
_Document.Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);
```

This is the [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af6z0wa2.aspx)

I'm not sure if you'll need the middle line or not. It's not from the original source it's from [here](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/449306/not-saving-documents-using-microsoft-office-interop-word)

Answer (score 0):

See the [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196343(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Document class described in MSDN. If you need to omit the parameter and use the default value - pass the Type.Missing parameter.